# Xamarin c#: Parse.com relation table seems to only work one way?

Tags: parse-platform, orm

I'm working with Xamarin in Visual Studio.

I'm utilizing Parse (via SashiDo.com) and I'm trying to create a relation between my `Users` and the ParseObjects in a table called called `Dispatch`, like so:

```
        //Make the new Dispatch object
        var parseDispatch = new Parse.ParseObject("Dispatch");
        //Save it
        await parseDispatch.SaveAsync();

        //...Setting various properties on the Dispatch object...

        //Get a list of users (via another method)
        IEnumerable<ParseUser> usersToLink = UsersToLinkToDispatch(); //And have verified elsewhere that this indeed returns a collection of ParseUsers

        //Go through the users collection
        usersToLink.ToList().ForEach( async (user) => {

            //Get or create the dispatches-tracking relation for this user
            var dispatchObjectRelation = parseDispatch.GetRelation<ParseObject>("DispatchesTracked");

            //Add the current user to that tracker relation
            dispatchObjectRelation.Add(user);

            //save the dispatch to update the relation
            await parseDispatch.SaveAsync();
        });
```

So, when I go to inspect my tables in SashiDo, if I look at the Dispatches table, I see a proper-looking relational link, and if I click on that link, I see the list of linked Users. So far so good, right?

But if I look at the Users table, while there also seems to be a proper-looking relational link, when I click on it I do *not* see a list of linked Dispatches.

Is this expected behavior, or is this apparent one-way-ness of the relational link an error?

Comment: Yes. It is the expected behavior. If you created a relation field in the Dispatch class, via dashboard, you will only see the Users associated to each Dispatch, but you will not see the Dispatches associated to each User.

Comment: thanks davi, if you want to make this an answer i'll award it to you.